# What's happen when I open a project, on another project in Visual Studio 2013 that is running?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, runtime, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a problem that it's very weird for me!
I have 2 solution in two difference places.both of them are similar but one of them is older than another.
There is a problem in new version when I run a Kendo Grid on it.But when I open old version of solution beside new version, I emphasis just open no run, the new version will be okay! 
It's very very weird for me that how this problem can occur and how another solution can fix this problem just by opening the solution?
I think something is damaged but I don't know, what is that.
How can I solve this problem?

I've used Visual Studio 2013,C# and Kendo for Asp.net MVC.

> **Jahan.Blog.sln file: (new version)**

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
Visual Studio 2013
VisualStudioVersion = 12.0.31101.0
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Jahan.Blog.Model.DbFirst", "Applications\Jahan.Blog.Model.DbFirst\Jahan.Blog.Model.DbFirst.csproj", "{EE04EA76-1CFE-4484-B6C5-7C5232B3F1C4}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Jahan.Blog.Model", "Applications\Jahan.Blog.Model\Jahan.Blog.Model.csproj", "{944336E2-DC84-451C-BB1D-86C619A1770D}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Jahan.Blog.Web.Mvc", "Applications\Jahan.Blog.Web.Mvc\Jahan.Blog.Web.Mvc.csproj", "{09F658AE-5DDD-44DA-950D-6C3CF1259206}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Jahan.Blog.Web.TestHtml", "Applications\Jahan.Blog.Web.TestHtml\Jahan.Blog.Web.TestHtml.csproj", "{69D02E00-1663-464B-B07A-C129B8D29C8D}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Test.HtmlPage", "Applications\Test.HtmlPage\Test.HtmlPage.csproj", "{5C1E487D-6421-470E-9398-11CB230D5435}"
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Blog", "Blog", "{790963C2-9AB6-440E-96B3-48A29CF9663A}"
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "ProjectsForTest", "ProjectsForTest", "{F7F4128F-4141-434A-9655-8BA7B6806570}"
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Infrastructure", "Infrastructure", "{C3F7006C-B13C-447E-BABB-6561B38EB71B}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Jahan.Infrastructure.DataAccess", "Applications\Jahan.Infrastructure.DataAccess\Jahan.Infrastructure.DataAccess.csproj", "{511E08CF-B782-49AF-BA10-E52BCDA4140D}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Jahan.Infrastructure.Entity", "Applications\Jahan.Infrastructure.Entity\Jahan.Infrastructure.Entity.csproj", "{C535FF81-2D39-4EB7-8342-63C76A3CE5D6}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Jahan.Blog.DataAccess", "Applications\Jahan.Blog.DataAccess\Jahan.Blog.DataAccess.csproj", "{FFDEF719-387C-4E9D-AAA1-83175CFC74C1}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Jahan.Blog.ViewModel", "Applications\Jahan.Blog.ViewModel\Jahan.Blog.ViewModel.csproj", "{AF29C1B7-3958-46E7-AB56-D98875C2BEAF}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Jahan.Infrastructure.Helper", "Applications\Jahan.Infrastructure.Helper\Jahan.Infrastructure.Helper.csproj", "{A734297F-B425-4396-8B0F-7DDF9AED5CF7}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Jahan.Blog.Common", "Applications\Jahan.Blog.Common\Jahan.Blog.Common.csproj", "{AF0CF334-2694-47D9-B4C7-FF371327DA36}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Jahan.Infrastructure.Identity", "Applications\Jahan.Infrastructure.Identity\Jahan.Infrastructure.Identity.csproj", "{FADF2BF8-8102-4045-B075-1619696C3D01}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Jahan.Blog.BLL", "Applications\Jahan.Blog.BLL\Jahan.Blog.BLL.csproj", "{2F19C372-358F-4632-A0F9-6631BBB4F492}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SourceCodeControl) = preSolution
        SccNumberOfProjects = 14
        SccProjectUniqueName0 = Applications\\Test.HtmlPage\\Test.HtmlPage.csproj
        SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName0 = Jahan.Blog.sln
        SccProjectName0 = \u0022$/Blog/Jahan.Blog.root/Jahan.Blog/Applications/Test.HtmlPage\u0022,\u0020MLAAAAAA
        SccLocalPath0 = Applications\\Test.HtmlPage
        SccLocalPath1 = .
        SccProjectUniqueName2 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.BLL\\Jahan.Blog.BLL.csproj
        SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName2 = Jahan.Blog.sln
        SccLocalPath2 = .
        SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection2 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.BLL\\
        SccProjectUniqueName3 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.Common\\Jahan.Blog.Common.csproj
        SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName3 = Jahan.Blog.sln
        SccLocalPath3 = .
        SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection3 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.Common\\
        SccProjectUniqueName4 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.DataAccess\\Jahan.Blog.DataAccess.csproj
        SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName4 = Jahan.Blog.sln
        SccLocalPath4 = .
        SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection4 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.DataAccess\\
        SccProjectUniqueName5 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.Model.DbFirst\\Jahan.Blog.Model.DbFirst.csproj
        SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName5 = Jahan.Blog.sln
        SccLocalPath5 = .
        SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection5 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.Model.DbFirst\\
        SccProjectUniqueName6 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.Model\\Jahan.Blog.Model.csproj
        SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName6 = Jahan.Blog.sln
        SccLocalPath6 = .
        SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection6 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.Model\\
        SccProjectUniqueName7 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.ViewModel\\Jahan.Blog.ViewModel.csproj
        SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName7 = Jahan.Blog.sln
        SccLocalPath7 = .
        SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection7 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.ViewModel\\
        SccProjectUniqueName8 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.Web.Mvc\\Jahan.Blog.Web.Mvc.csproj
        SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName8 = Jahan.Blog.sln
        SccLocalPath8 = .
        SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection8 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.Web.Mvc\\
        SccProjectUniqueName9 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.Web.TestHtml\\Jahan.Blog.Web.TestHtml.csproj
        SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName9 = Jahan.Blog.sln
        SccLocalPath9 = .
        SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection9 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.Web.TestHtml\\
        SccProjectUniqueName10 = Applications\\Jahan.Infrastructure.DataAccess\\Jahan.Infrastructure.DataAccess.csproj
        SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName10 = Jahan.Blog.sln
        SccLocalPath10 = .
        SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection10 = Applications\\Jahan.Infrastructure.DataAccess\\
        SccProjectUniqueName11 = Applications\\Jahan.Infrastructure.Entity\\Jahan.Infrastructure.Entity.csproj
        SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName11 = Jahan.Blog.sln
        SccLocalPath11 = .
        SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection11 = Applications\\Jahan.Infrastructure.Entity\\
        SccProjectUniqueName12 = Applications\\Jahan.Infrastructure.Helper\\Jahan.Infrastructure.Helper.csproj
        SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName12 = Jahan.Blog.sln
        SccLocalPath12 = .
        SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection12 = Applications\\Jahan.Infrastructure.Helper\\
        SccProjectUniqueName13 = Applications\\Jahan.Infrastructure.Identity\\Jahan.Infrastructure.Identity.csproj
        SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName13 = Jahan.Blog.sln
        SccLocalPath13 = .
        SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection13 = Applications\\Jahan.Infrastructure.Identity\\
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {EE04EA76-1CFE-4484-B6C5-7C5232B3F1C4}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {EE04EA76-1CFE-4484-B6C5-7C5232B3F1C4}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {EE04EA76-1CFE-4484-B6C5-7C5232B3F1C4}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {EE04EA76-1CFE-4484-B6C5-7C5232B3F1C4}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {944336E2-DC84-451C-BB1D-86C619A1770D}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {944336E2-DC84-451C-BB1D-86C619A1770D}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {944336E2-DC84-451C-BB1D-86C619A1770D}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {944336E2-DC84-451C-BB1D-86C619A1770D}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {09F658AE-5DDD-44DA-950D-6C3CF1259206}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {09F658AE-5DDD-44DA-950D-6C3CF1259206}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {09F658AE-5DDD-44DA-950D-6C3CF1259206}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {09F658AE-5DDD-44DA-950D-6C3CF1259206}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {69D02E00-1663-464B-B07A-C129B8D29C8D}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {69D02E00-1663-464B-B07A-C129B8D29C8D}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {69D02E00-1663-464B-B07A-C129B8D29C8D}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {69D02E00-1663-464B-B07A-C129B8D29C8D}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {5C1E487D-6421-470E-9398-11CB230D5435}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {5C1E487D-6421-470E-9398-11CB230D5435}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {5C1E487D-6421-470E-9398-11CB230D5435}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {5C1E487D-6421-470E-9398-11CB230D5435}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {511E08CF-B782-49AF-BA10-E52BCDA4140D}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {511E08CF-B782-49AF-BA10-E52BCDA4140D}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {511E08CF-B782-49AF-BA10-E52BCDA4140D}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {511E08CF-B782-49AF-BA10-E52BCDA4140D}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {C535FF81-2D39-4EB7-8342-63C76A3CE5D6}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {C535FF81-2D39-4EB7-8342-63C76A3CE5D6}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {C535FF81-2D39-4EB7-8342-63C76A3CE5D6}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {C535FF81-2D39-4EB7-8342-63C76A3CE5D6}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {FFDEF719-387C-4E9D-AAA1-83175CFC74C1}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {FFDEF719-387C-4E9D-AAA1-83175CFC74C1}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {FFDEF719-387C-4E9D-AAA1-83175CFC74C1}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {FFDEF719-387C-4E9D-AAA1-83175CFC74C1}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {AF29C1B7-3958-46E7-AB56-D98875C2BEAF}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {AF29C1B7-3958-46E7-AB56-D98875C2BEAF}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {AF29C1B7-3958-46E7-AB56-D98875C2BEAF}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {AF29C1B7-3958-46E7-AB56-D98875C2BEAF}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {A734297F-B425-4396-8B0F-7DDF9AED5CF7}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {A734297F-B425-4396-8B0F-7DDF9AED5CF7}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {A734297F-B425-4396-8B0F-7DDF9AED5CF7}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {A734297F-B425-4396-8B0F-7DDF9AED5CF7}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {AF0CF334-2694-47D9-B4C7-FF371327DA36}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {AF0CF334-2694-47D9-B4C7-FF371327DA36}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {AF0CF334-2694-47D9-B4C7-FF371327DA36}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {AF0CF334-2694-47D9-B4C7-FF371327DA36}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {FADF2BF8-8102-4045-B075-1619696C3D01}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {FADF2BF8-8102-4045-B075-1619696C3D01}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {FADF2BF8-8102-4045-B075-1619696C3D01}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {FADF2BF8-8102-4045-B075-1619696C3D01}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {2F19C372-358F-4632-A0F9-6631BBB4F492}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {2F19C372-358F-4632-A0F9-6631BBB4F492}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {2F19C372-358F-4632-A0F9-6631BBB4F492}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {2F19C372-358F-4632-A0F9-6631BBB4F492}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(NestedProjects) = preSolution
        {EE04EA76-1CFE-4484-B6C5-7C5232B3F1C4} = {F7F4128F-4141-434A-9655-8BA7B6806570}
        {944336E2-DC84-451C-BB1D-86C619A1770D} = {790963C2-9AB6-440E-96B3-48A29CF9663A}
        {09F658AE-5DDD-44DA-950D-6C3CF1259206} = {790963C2-9AB6-440E-96B3-48A29CF9663A}
        {69D02E00-1663-464B-B07A-C129B8D29C8D} = {F7F4128F-4141-434A-9655-8BA7B6806570}
        {5C1E487D-6421-470E-9398-11CB230D5435} = {F7F4128F-4141-434A-9655-8BA7B6806570}
        {511E08CF-B782-49AF-BA10-E52BCDA4140D} = {C3F7006C-B13C-447E-BABB-6561B38EB71B}
        {C535FF81-2D39-4EB7-8342-63C76A3CE5D6} = {C3F7006C-B13C-447E-BABB-6561B38EB71B}
        {FFDEF719-387C-4E9D-AAA1-83175CFC74C1} = {790963C2-9AB6-440E-96B3-48A29CF9663A}
        {AF29C1B7-3958-46E7-AB56-D98875C2BEAF} = {790963C2-9AB6-440E-96B3-48A29CF9663A}
        {A734297F-B425-4396-8B0F-7DDF9AED5CF7} = {C3F7006C-B13C-447E-BABB-6561B38EB71B}
        {AF0CF334-2694-47D9-B4C7-FF371327DA36} = {790963C2-9AB6-440E-96B3-48A29CF9663A}
        {FADF2BF8-8102-4045-B075-1619696C3D01} = {C3F7006C-B13C-447E-BABB-6561B38EB71B}
        {2F19C372-358F-4632-A0F9-6631BBB4F492} = {790963C2-9AB6-440E-96B3-48A29CF9663A}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

> **Jahan.Blog.sln file: (old version)**

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
Visual Studio 2013
VisualStudioVersion = 12.0.31101.0
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Jahan.Blog.Model.DbFirst", "Applications\Jahan.Blog.Model.DbFirst\Jahan.Blog.Model.DbFirst.csproj", "{EE04EA76-1CFE-4484-B6C5-7C5232B3F1C4}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Jahan.Blog.Model", "Applications\Jahan.Blog.Model\Jahan.Blog.Model.csproj", "{944336E2-DC84-451C-BB1D-86C619A1770D}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Jahan.Blog.Web.Mvc", "Applications\Jahan.Blog.Web.Mvc\Jahan.Blog.Web.Mvc.csproj", "{09F658AE-5DDD-44DA-950D-6C3CF1259206}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Jahan.Blog.Web.TestHtml", "Applications\Jahan.Blog.Web.TestHtml\Jahan.Blog.Web.TestHtml.csproj", "{69D02E00-1663-464B-B07A-C129B8D29C8D}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Test.HtmlPage", "Applications\Test.HtmlPage\Test.HtmlPage.csproj", "{5C1E487D-6421-470E-9398-11CB230D5435}"
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Blog", "Blog", "{790963C2-9AB6-440E-96B3-48A29CF9663A}"
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "ProjectsForTest", "ProjectsForTest", "{F7F4128F-4141-434A-9655-8BA7B6806570}"
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Infrastructure", "Infrastructure", "{C3F7006C-B13C-447E-BABB-6561B38EB71B}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Jahan.Infrastructure.DataAccess", "Applications\Jahan.Infrastructure.DataAccess\Jahan.Infrastructure.DataAccess.csproj", "{511E08CF-B782-49AF-BA10-E52BCDA4140D}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Jahan.Infrastructure.Entity", "Applications\Jahan.Infrastructure.Entity\Jahan.Infrastructure.Entity.csproj", "{C535FF81-2D39-4EB7-8342-63C76A3CE5D6}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Jahan.Blog.DataAccess", "Applications\Jahan.Blog.DataAccess\Jahan.Blog.DataAccess.csproj", "{FFDEF719-387C-4E9D-AAA1-83175CFC74C1}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Jahan.Blog.ViewModel", "Applications\Jahan.Blog.ViewModel\Jahan.Blog.ViewModel.csproj", "{AF29C1B7-3958-46E7-AB56-D98875C2BEAF}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Jahan.Infrastructure.Helper", "Applications\Jahan.Infrastructure.Helper\Jahan.Infrastructure.Helper.csproj", "{A734297F-B425-4396-8B0F-7DDF9AED5CF7}"
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "TestCase", "TestCase", "{AB528F30-CE93-4ECA-B7AF-F5A444E9D575}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "SelectArticlesByCriteria_ConsoleApp", "Applications\TestCase\SelectArticlesByCriteria_ConsoleApp\SelectArticlesByCriteria_ConsoleApp.csproj", "{5EDD1CDA-C00E-47BC-BED5-2D63035971F8}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Jahan.Blog.Common", "Applications\Jahan.Blog.Common\Jahan.Blog.Common.csproj", "{AF0CF334-2694-47D9-B4C7-FF371327DA36}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Jahan.Infrastructure.Identity", "Applications\Jahan.Infrastructure.Identity\Jahan.Infrastructure.Identity.csproj", "{FADF2BF8-8102-4045-B075-1619696C3D01}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Jahan.Blog.BLL", "Applications\Jahan.Blog.BLL\Jahan.Blog.BLL.csproj", "{2F19C372-358F-4632-A0F9-6631BBB4F492}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {EE04EA76-1CFE-4484-B6C5-7C5232B3F1C4}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {EE04EA76-1CFE-4484-B6C5-7C5232B3F1C4}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {EE04EA76-1CFE-4484-B6C5-7C5232B3F1C4}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {EE04EA76-1CFE-4484-B6C5-7C5232B3F1C4}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {944336E2-DC84-451C-BB1D-86C619A1770D}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {944336E2-DC84-451C-BB1D-86C619A1770D}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {944336E2-DC84-451C-BB1D-86C619A1770D}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {944336E2-DC84-451C-BB1D-86C619A1770D}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {09F658AE-5DDD-44DA-950D-6C3CF1259206}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {09F658AE-5DDD-44DA-950D-6C3CF1259206}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {09F658AE-5DDD-44DA-950D-6C3CF1259206}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {09F658AE-5DDD-44DA-950D-6C3CF1259206}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {69D02E00-1663-464B-B07A-C129B8D29C8D}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {69D02E00-1663-464B-B07A-C129B8D29C8D}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {69D02E00-1663-464B-B07A-C129B8D29C8D}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {69D02E00-1663-464B-B07A-C129B8D29C8D}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {5C1E487D-6421-470E-9398-11CB230D5435}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {5C1E487D-6421-470E-9398-11CB230D5435}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {5C1E487D-6421-470E-9398-11CB230D5435}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {5C1E487D-6421-470E-9398-11CB230D5435}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {511E08CF-B782-49AF-BA10-E52BCDA4140D}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {511E08CF-B782-49AF-BA10-E52BCDA4140D}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {511E08CF-B782-49AF-BA10-E52BCDA4140D}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {511E08CF-B782-49AF-BA10-E52BCDA4140D}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {C535FF81-2D39-4EB7-8342-63C76A3CE5D6}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {C535FF81-2D39-4EB7-8342-63C76A3CE5D6}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {C535FF81-2D39-4EB7-8342-63C76A3CE5D6}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {C535FF81-2D39-4EB7-8342-63C76A3CE5D6}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {FFDEF719-387C-4E9D-AAA1-83175CFC74C1}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {FFDEF719-387C-4E9D-AAA1-83175CFC74C1}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {FFDEF719-387C-4E9D-AAA1-83175CFC74C1}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {FFDEF719-387C-4E9D-AAA1-83175CFC74C1}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {AF29C1B7-3958-46E7-AB56-D98875C2BEAF}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {AF29C1B7-3958-46E7-AB56-D98875C2BEAF}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {AF29C1B7-3958-46E7-AB56-D98875C2BEAF}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {AF29C1B7-3958-46E7-AB56-D98875C2BEAF}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {A734297F-B425-4396-8B0F-7DDF9AED5CF7}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {A734297F-B425-4396-8B0F-7DDF9AED5CF7}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {A734297F-B425-4396-8B0F-7DDF9AED5CF7}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {A734297F-B425-4396-8B0F-7DDF9AED5CF7}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {5EDD1CDA-C00E-47BC-BED5-2D63035971F8}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {5EDD1CDA-C00E-47BC-BED5-2D63035971F8}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {5EDD1CDA-C00E-47BC-BED5-2D63035971F8}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {5EDD1CDA-C00E-47BC-BED5-2D63035971F8}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {AF0CF334-2694-47D9-B4C7-FF371327DA36}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {AF0CF334-2694-47D9-B4C7-FF371327DA36}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {AF0CF334-2694-47D9-B4C7-FF371327DA36}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {AF0CF334-2694-47D9-B4C7-FF371327DA36}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {FADF2BF8-8102-4045-B075-1619696C3D01}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {FADF2BF8-8102-4045-B075-1619696C3D01}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {FADF2BF8-8102-4045-B075-1619696C3D01}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {FADF2BF8-8102-4045-B075-1619696C3D01}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {2F19C372-358F-4632-A0F9-6631BBB4F492}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {2F19C372-358F-4632-A0F9-6631BBB4F492}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {2F19C372-358F-4632-A0F9-6631BBB4F492}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {2F19C372-358F-4632-A0F9-6631BBB4F492}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(NestedProjects) = preSolution
        {EE04EA76-1CFE-4484-B6C5-7C5232B3F1C4} = {F7F4128F-4141-434A-9655-8BA7B6806570}
        {944336E2-DC84-451C-BB1D-86C619A1770D} = {790963C2-9AB6-440E-96B3-48A29CF9663A}
        {09F658AE-5DDD-44DA-950D-6C3CF1259206} = {790963C2-9AB6-440E-96B3-48A29CF9663A}
        {69D02E00-1663-464B-B07A-C129B8D29C8D} = {F7F4128F-4141-434A-9655-8BA7B6806570}
        {5C1E487D-6421-470E-9398-11CB230D5435} = {F7F4128F-4141-434A-9655-8BA7B6806570}
        {511E08CF-B782-49AF-BA10-E52BCDA4140D} = {C3F7006C-B13C-447E-BABB-6561B38EB71B}
        {C535FF81-2D39-4EB7-8342-63C76A3CE5D6} = {C3F7006C-B13C-447E-BABB-6561B38EB71B}
        {FFDEF719-387C-4E9D-AAA1-83175CFC74C1} = {790963C2-9AB6-440E-96B3-48A29CF9663A}
        {AF29C1B7-3958-46E7-AB56-D98875C2BEAF} = {790963C2-9AB6-440E-96B3-48A29CF9663A}
        {A734297F-B425-4396-8B0F-7DDF9AED5CF7} = {C3F7006C-B13C-447E-BABB-6561B38EB71B}
        {5EDD1CDA-C00E-47BC-BED5-2D63035971F8} = {AB528F30-CE93-4ECA-B7AF-F5A444E9D575}
        {AF0CF334-2694-47D9-B4C7-FF371327DA36} = {790963C2-9AB6-440E-96B3-48A29CF9663A}
        {FADF2BF8-8102-4045-B075-1619696C3D01} = {C3F7006C-B13C-447E-BABB-6561B38EB71B}
        {2F19C372-358F-4632-A0F9-6631BBB4F492} = {790963C2-9AB6-440E-96B3-48A29CF9663A}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

[image: Architecture view]

Comment: Have you checked the solution file to see if there are unintentional cross-dependencies? eg Something in the solution or project is unexpectedly dependent upon something in the other? Have you tried opening the solutions in reverse order to see if the behavior persists?

Comment: @DavidW: I checked but I have no idea about them.You can see them sln files now! 
But I changed project Url for new version to http://localhost:28513 and old version has remained to http://localhost:28552/. 
Now there is no collision. It means if I run new version even old version  be opened, no data has been showed in new version!

Comment: Maybe in old solution you have references with parameter "copy local = true" so when you open old solution it copies required dlls, while new solution doesnt make local copies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This is just a comparison of your two files.

Your old version appears to be a Console Application. Was this to test with?

```
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "TestCase", "TestCase", "{AB528F30-CE93-4ECA-B7AF-F5A444E9D575}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "SelectArticlesByCriteria_ConsoleApp", "Applications\TestCase\SelectArticlesByCriteria_ConsoleApp\SelectArticlesByCriteria_ConsoleApp.csproj", "{5EDD1CDA-C00E-47BC-BED5-2D63035971F8}"
EndProject
```

Your new version, however, appears to be under Source Control:

```
GlobalSection(SourceCodeControl) = preSolution
    SccNumberOfProjects = 14
    SccProjectUniqueName0 = Applications\\Test.HtmlPage\\Test.HtmlPage.csproj
    SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName0 = Jahan.Blog.sln
    SccProjectName0 = \u0022$/Blog/Jahan.Blog.root/Jahan.Blog/Applications/Test.HtmlPage\u0022,\u0020MLAAAAAA
    SccLocalPath0 = Applications\\Test.HtmlPage
    SccLocalPath1 = .
    SccProjectUniqueName2 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.BLL\\Jahan.Blog.BLL.csproj
    SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName2 = Jahan.Blog.sln
    SccLocalPath2 = .
    SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection2 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.BLL\\
    SccProjectUniqueName3 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.Common\\Jahan.Blog.Common.csproj
    SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName3 = Jahan.Blog.sln
    SccLocalPath3 = .
    SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection3 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.Common\\
    SccProjectUniqueName4 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.DataAccess\\Jahan.Blog.DataAccess.csproj
    SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName4 = Jahan.Blog.sln
    SccLocalPath4 = .
    SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection4 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.DataAccess\\
    SccProjectUniqueName5 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.Model.DbFirst\\Jahan.Blog.Model.DbFirst.csproj
    SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName5 = Jahan.Blog.sln
    SccLocalPath5 = .
    SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection5 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.Model.DbFirst\\
    SccProjectUniqueName6 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.Model\\Jahan.Blog.Model.csproj
    SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName6 = Jahan.Blog.sln
    SccLocalPath6 = .
    SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection6 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.Model\\
    SccProjectUniqueName7 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.ViewModel\\Jahan.Blog.ViewModel.csproj
    SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName7 = Jahan.Blog.sln
    SccLocalPath7 = .
    SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection7 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.ViewModel\\
    SccProjectUniqueName8 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.Web.Mvc\\Jahan.Blog.Web.Mvc.csproj
    SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName8 = Jahan.Blog.sln
    SccLocalPath8 = .
    SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection8 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.Web.Mvc\\
    SccProjectUniqueName9 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.Web.TestHtml\\Jahan.Blog.Web.TestHtml.csproj
    SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName9 = Jahan.Blog.sln
    SccLocalPath9 = .
    SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection9 = Applications\\Jahan.Blog.Web.TestHtml\\
    SccProjectUniqueName10 = Applications\\Jahan.Infrastructure.DataAccess\\Jahan.Infrastructure.DataAccess.csproj
    SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName10 = Jahan.Blog.sln
    SccLocalPath10 = .
    SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection10 = Applications\\Jahan.Infrastructure.DataAccess\\
    SccProjectUniqueName11 = Applications\\Jahan.Infrastructure.Entity\\Jahan.Infrastructure.Entity.csproj
    SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName11 = Jahan.Blog.sln
    SccLocalPath11 = .
    SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection11 = Applications\\Jahan.Infrastructure.Entity\\
    SccProjectUniqueName12 = Applications\\Jahan.Infrastructure.Helper\\Jahan.Infrastructure.Helper.csproj
    SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName12 = Jahan.Blog.sln
    SccLocalPath12 = .
    SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection12 = Applications\\Jahan.Infrastructure.Helper\\
    SccProjectUniqueName13 = Applications\\Jahan.Infrastructure.Identity\\Jahan.Infrastructure.Identity.csproj
    SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName13 = Jahan.Blog.sln
    SccLocalPath13 = .
    SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection13 = Applications\\Jahan.Infrastructure.Identity\\
EndGlobalSection
```

It also has another `preSolution` section that immediately follows, so you could be overwriting something in Visual Studio.

Next, in your old copy, there are these `postSolution` lines that are missing:

```
    {5EDD1CDA-C00E-47BC-BED5-2D63035971F8}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {5EDD1CDA-C00E-47BC-BED5-2D63035971F8}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    {5EDD1CDA-C00E-47BC-BED5-2D63035971F8}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {5EDD1CDA-C00E-47BC-BED5-2D63035971F8}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
```

I don't know what those two are, but they might be what you are missing.

Last, you have a section called `GlobalSection(NestedProjects) = preSolution` in the old version that has 1 line that the new version lacks:

```
    {5EDD1CDA-C00E-47BC-BED5-2D63035971F8} = {AB528F30-CE93-4ECA-B7AF-F5A444E9D575}
```

It could be that the Visual Studio compiler is debugging with files that it has in memory, and it is sharing the memory between the two open instances.

Very interesting!